# how to add and remove same item in ListView in android?

Tags: android

I have 3 string text 'A' , 'B' , 'C' and it is added in ListView . And one TexView as Title .

```
1 . When i click on List-view Item 'A' this item will be display in TexView and Item 'A' remove from ListView.Only 'B','C' remianing in List.
2 . When i click on List-view Item 'B' this item will be display in TexView and same Item 'B' remove from ListView and 'A','C' will be showing in ListView. 
3 . When i click on List-view Item 'C' this item will be display in TexView and same Item 'C' remove from ListView and 'A','B' will be showing in ListView.
```

It means first i have 3 item in my ListView after adding in textView as title only 2 item will be display every time in ListView. How to work with this logic.Can someone help me .

Here is my code.

```
String[] values = new String[] { "A", "B", "C"};

arr = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(values));
                filterPost_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.filter_popup_list_item , R.id.text_filter_title, arr);
                filter_list.setAdapter(filterPost_adapter);


filter_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
                    {
                        String selectedFromList =(filter_list.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
                        Log.e("selectedFromList ", " = " + selectedFromList);
                        removeItemFromList(position);

                        if(selectedFromList.equals("A"))
                        {
                            textSearch.setText("A");
                            populate_MyAllPostList();

                        }
                        if(selectedFromList.equals("B"))
                        {
                            textSearch.setText("B");
                            populateList();

                        }
                        if(selectedFromList.equals("B"))
                        {
                            textSearch.setText("B");
                            populate_StarPost();

                        }
                    }
                });



 protected void removeItemFromList(int position) {
        final int deletePosition = position;
        arr.remove(deletePosition);
        filterPost_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        filterPost_adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only removed the item from your **Activity** `ArrayList` I supose

to update the `Listview` you have to call a method from the adapter and update it's `arraylist` before calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Exemple :

```
In your activity
-> here remove the item from the activity arraylist and then
filterPost_adapter.updatelist(arrayListWithRemovedItem);
```

In your adapter :

```
public void updateList(ArrayList list)
{
    mLocalArrayList = list;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Item remove properly.But before removing item i want to add TextView String in list-view which is displaying listview item in  TextView  before removing second item from listview.

Comment: If you also want to update some of the list cells (you are not very clear on this) you should do a if() test in getView() depending on what is the condition  and change the cell's views when they are created/recycled

Comment: I think you are not understand my question.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, I'm not influent in English. So that's why writes  above 3 points in my post 1 ,2  ,3 for clearer.

Answer (score 0):

in on item click write below code:

```
     @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
    if(filterPost_adapter.getCount()==3){
          String data = filterPost_adapter.getItem(position);
            textVeiw.setText(data);
         filterPost_adapter.remove(data);
    }else{
        String temp = textView.getText().toString();
        String data = filterPost_adapter.getItem(position);
        textVeiw.setText(data);
        filterPost_adapter.remove(data);
       filterPost_adapter.add(temp);
    }
 }
```